# How can I write dynamic explode function(to explode multiple columns) in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, explode

I need to write a dynamic Scala class. It will take three parameter as input. input_dataframe, list of columns to be exploded and delimiter. consider i have below dataframe.

```
DataBase     TableName       Value
dbdev        table1_name     Value1#Value2#Value3
```

After exploding I am expecting result as below

```
DataBase     TableName       Value                   Value_Exploded
dbdev        table1_name     Value1#Value2#Value3    Value1
dbdev        table1_name     Value1#Value2#Value3    Value2
dbdev        table1_name     Value1#Value2#Value3    Value3
```

So my question is how to write a Scala class to achieve above. **Constraint is**, it has to be generic. it might get different Dataframes. And columns which needs to be exploded(multiple), need to be passed.

I am able to achieve this, when i need to explode only one single column. Please find below -

```
val explodeColumnName = "Value" //column which i need to explode
val explodeColumnBy = "#" //delimiter

val explodeDF = df.select(df.col("*"), explode(split(col(explodeColumnName), s"$explodeColumnBy")).as (explodeColumnName+"_Exploded"))
```

But I am **failing when i need to explode multiple columns dynamically**. Ex. let's say, i need to explode 4 columns of a Dataframe df.

Any help/suggestions/advice would be really great.

Thank you!

Comment: Exploding multiple columns in select will not work.. you need to use withColumn function or try below solution .. let me know if it's not working..

Answer (score 1):

Check below code.

```
scala> val df = Seq(
     (
         "dbdev",
         "table1_name",
         "Value1#Value2#Value3",
         "Sample1#Sample2#Sample3"
    )
)
.toDF("database","tablename","value","sample")
```

```
scala> df.show(false)
+--------+-----------+--------------------+-----------------------+
|database|tablename  |value               |sample                 |
+--------+-----------+--------------------+-----------------------+
|dbdev   |table1_name|Value1#Value2#Value3|Sample1#Sample2#Sample3|
+--------+-----------+--------------------+-----------------------+
```

Importing required libraries

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column,DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame}
```

Defining `DFHelper` class.

**Note** - Don't use `explode` as function name inside `DFHelper` class, `explode` is already available in built-in functions, so I have used `explodeM` as function.

```
scala> implicit class DFHelper(inDF: DataFrame) {
           import inDF.sparkSession.implicits._          
            def explodeM(delimiter:String,columns:Column*): DataFrame = {
               columns.foldLeft(inDF)((indf,column) => indf
               .withColumn(column.toString,split(column,delimiter))
               .withColumn(column.toString,explode(column))
               )
           }
      }
```

```
scala> df.explodeM("#",$"value").show(false) // one column exploding
+--------+-----------+------+-----------------------+
|database|tablename  |value |sample                 |
+--------+-----------+------+-----------------------+
|dbdev   |table1_name|Value1|Sample1#Sample2#Sample3|
|dbdev   |table1_name|Value2|Sample1#Sample2#Sample3|
|dbdev   |table1_name|Value3|Sample1#Sample2#Sample3|
+--------+-----------+------+-----------------------+
```

```
scala> df.explodeM("#",$"value",$"sample").show(false) // two columns exploding
+--------+-----------+------+-------+
|database|tablename  |value |sample |
+--------+-----------+------+-------+
|dbdev   |table1_name|Value1|Sample1|
|dbdev   |table1_name|Value1|Sample2|
|dbdev   |table1_name|Value1|Sample3|
|dbdev   |table1_name|Value2|Sample1|
|dbdev   |table1_name|Value2|Sample2|
|dbdev   |table1_name|Value2|Sample3|
|dbdev   |table1_name|Value3|Sample1|
|dbdev   |table1_name|Value3|Sample2|
|dbdev   |table1_name|Value3|Sample3|
+--------+-----------+------+-------+
```

Comment: What if column names are itself dynamic? I.e you dont know column names. The structure is like a big array of array of array of.....arrays.